# Полезные тревоги могут вернуть?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Дело в том, что дается только 10 тревог. Как можно увеличить их количество или восстановить? Не совсем понимаю, как привлечь внимание сообщества к неподходящим сообщениям, когда тревоги закончатся.

Comment: Они возвращаются по мере обработки очереди тревог :)

Comment: И по мере появления объективно неподходящих сообщений.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Отмечать тревогой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). Там есть ответы на то, как работает данная система.

> Изначально вы можете отметить тревогой 10 сообщений в день. Количество
> может возрасти до 100:
>
> Вы получаете один дополнительный сигнал за каждые 2000 баллов
> репутации.
>
> Вы получаете дополнительные сигналы тревоги в случае если
> голосуете корректно.

Лучше всего, в первую очередь, привлекать внимание автора сообщения к проблеме или ошибке, которая была им допущена.

Тревогой следует пользоваться в крайних случаях:

- Если сообщение плохого качества, а вносимые в него правки значительно не улучшат его.
- Если сообщение грубо нарушает правила сайта.